# How many lawsuits has IBM lost?

Tags: corporate-law, legal-history

I'm looking for a list of lawsuits IBM was the defendant and lost, and also was the plaintiff and lost. I'm looking for well known ones that generally caught the public's interest. Does IBM always win in court because it's own law firm?

Comment: I suspect that the only people who have such a list are the IBM legal dept (and it won't be filtered by "caught the public's interest").

Comment: If you're just looking for "well known ones", that's an easy [web search](http://lmgtfy.com/?q=lawsuit+against+IBM). If you want a complete list, that'll take some legwork.

Comment: @david did yo actually read through the results? Most aren't about a specific legal case and many are just intended law suits or settlements, not the actual outcome.

Answer (score 2):

You can review the "Contingencies and commitments" section of IBM's annual reports to find named lawsuits (and estimated costs thereof) the management finds material to disclose to shareholders.   For your duration of interest, this should help identify the list major cases which you can research to determine outcomes.

[Online IBM annual reports](http://www.ibm.com/annualreport/)